# HTML5 audio stream stops after each song

Tags: html, audio, safari, streaming, icecast

i have an icecast server serving continuous mp3 stream. i tried to play it in html5 with the audio tag. in safari it shows up and plays, but the moment the song changes, the stream stops and will not start again, even it i press the play button.

does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: Post a link to your stream.  Chances are, you are getting metadata in your stream data, and your browser doesn't know what to do with it.  It is then corrupt MP3 data, so instead of skipping that frame and re-syncing, it just stops.

Comment: Does it work on any other browsers? What's your code like? Are you calling `audio.load()` (where `audio` is your audio object) when loading the new track?

Comment: I can confirm that Brad's comment is correct. I have this exact same behaviour for a continuous Icecast Vorbis stream. The stream works fine without metadata updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Firefox Bug “Firefox fails on chained ogg stream” [#455165](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455165) and **should be fixed in Firefox 20**.

Update: Sorry, didn't saw that you said you are streaming mp3. Firefox might have similar issues with mp3 too…